# Capturing a screenshot/preview of background windows in python? (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, screenshot, desktop-application

I am trying to get a preview of some background windows. Similar to Discord's/ Electron's capture feature preview or the Windows taskbar preview, but as a picture. I use windows 10, Python 3.10 and have not found a solution yet that doesn't involve bringing all windows to the foreground and croping the entire screenshot to its rectangle. The windows should ideally stay in place or be minimized.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's the problem, there is a bunch of different code in win32gui, pywinauto etc. that either uses some setToForeground() method that I want to avoid (multiple windows, no epilepsy indended) or doesn't exactly work. Just the name of a library that could help me with that would be enough. Like: I provide the hwnd or title of the window / or iterate trough them all, and as a result, I get an image of the window.